# Stop apps from moving Linux workspaces when switching KVM

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, window-manager, kvm-switch

Just installed CentOS Stream 9 on a new Lenovo T14 Gen 4 Intel.
I have an external display connected by HDMI.
I am using many workspaces with terminals.
When the HDMI cable is unplugged from the laptop, apps on the external display are moved from the external dispay to the laptop display.
This is a reasonable and necessary behavior for the user to maintain control / access to apps.

However, this is not reasonable when switching the external display using a KVM.Near as I can tell, the KVM I'm using does essentially the same thing as disconnecting / reconnecting the HDMI cable.
There does appear to be some logic that attempts to restore apps to the external display, but the result is always incorrect and unpredictable.
Sometimes apps are left on the laptop display.
Sometimes they move from other workspaces to the current workspace.

So the question is, is there a way to disable the moving of apps in reaction to displays changing?

Here's a tree of what's connected to the KVM:

```
kvm: 4x1 HDMI / USB 3.0, 4K, EDID, HDCP2.2
    display: XWAYLAND12 connected primary 3440x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 800mm x 350mm
    keyboard: USB wired
    mouse: USB wired
    laptop: CentOS 9 Stream: 21HD0073US (LENOVO_MT_21HD_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad T14 Gen 4), 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1345U, Raptor Lake-P [UHD Graphics], driver=i915
        display: XWAYLAND4 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 300mm x 190mm
    towerpc: Windows
    desktop: macOS
```

UPDATE:

Apparently this is a long-standing and pervasive issue in the mutter package:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1419
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/230#note_1551972
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2092
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1418
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1778983
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1574251
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1927948

The second link has an explanation that sounds plausible.

The issue can occur under a wide range of circumstances from suspend-resume (which I have since witnessed) or just locking the screen and not just when KVM switching.

Unfortunately there is zero activity on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is the brand and model of the KVM switch?
You need to have a KVM switch that has built-in EDID emulation and full-time EDID feeding to all conncted systems.